# How to serve a PDF file created by pdfkit.from_string() with Flask send_file()

Tags: flask, file-transfer, pdfkit

I have a pdfkit PDF that is working fine as a Sendgrid attachment, created by the following function:

```
def wish_lists_pdf(user=current_user):
    pdf_heading = "Thank you!"
    pdf_subheading = "Please find the Wish Lists you signed up to sponsor listed below."

    pdf_context = {
        'heading': pdf_heading,
        'subheading': pdf_subheading,
        'user': user,
    }
    css = os.path.join(basedir, 'static/main.css')
    pdf_content = render_template(
        'partials/email_lists_pdf.html', **pdf_context)

    path_wkhtmltopdf = app.config['WKHTMLTOPDF_EXE']
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)

    pdf_file = pdfkit.from_string(
        pdf_content, False, configuration=config, css=css)

    bytes_file = BytesIO(pdf_file)

    return bytes_file
```

Actually, sendgrid needs this line instead of the bytes encoding:

```
    encoded_file = base64.b64encode(pdf_attachment).decode()
```

I tried it with this encoding and the b64 encoding as different tutorials have suggested. I don't really understand the purpose of the encoding, so that may be some of the cause for my error. In any case, here is a route that I want to serve the PDF file:

```
@bp.route('download_lists_pdf/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def download_lists_pdf(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
    pdf_file = wish_lists_pdf(user=user)
    return send_file(
        pdf_file,
        as_attachment=True,
        attachment_filename="Wish List Reminder Page.pdf",
        mimetype='application/pdf',
        )
```

This downloads a completely blank, 0kb PDF file. Can someone help me understand how to use send_file() in a way that will allow me to serve this PDF from pdfkit? Again, as a Sendgrid attachment the file works fine.

Here's the sendgrid attachment config if that's helpful...

```
    context = {
        'heading': heading,
        'subheading': subheading,
        'user': user,
    }

    message = Mail(
        from_email=app.config['ADMIN_EMAIL'],
        to_emails=app.config['EMAIL_RECIPIENTS'],
        subject=email_subject,
        html_content=render_template('partials/email_lists.html', **context),
    )

    encoded_file = base64.b64encode(pdf_attachment).decode()

    attached_file = Attachment(
        FileContent(encoded_file),
        FileName('Wish List Reminder Page.pdf'),
        FileType('application/pdf'),
        Disposition('attachment')
    )
    message.attachment = attached_file

    sg = SendGridAPIClient(app.config['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
    response = sg.send(message)
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

**Edit: tried below and it didn't work**

```
    bytes_file = BytesIO(pdf_file)

    return bytes(bytes_file), 200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="Wish List reminder sheet.pdf"'}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the PDF as `bytes_file`,

```
return bytes(byte_file), 200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="nameofyourchoice.pdf"'}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I tried that and it gave me this error: TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a BytesIO.

Comment: Try `bytes(byte_file)`. The code I pulled that from had already done that. I fixed the answer above.

Comment: Hmmm, is the edit above what you mean? I tried that and got TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as integer

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to return PDF file as a response then you can try this-

```
pdf = BytesIO(pdf_attachment)
response = pdf.getvalue()
pdf.close()
return response, 200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="name_of_file.pdf"'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a blank template.pdf file in my templates directory then did this in the from_string function

```
pdfkit.from_string(
        pdf_content, "templates/template.pdf", configuration=config, css=css
    )
```

i.e pass the path to your blank template.pdf as the output instead of `False`
You will then invoke `send_file` like so:

```
return send_file(
        'templates/template.pdf',
        mimetype="pdf",
        download_name="Wish List Reminder Page.pdf",
        as_attachment=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines were useful for me, to redirect to a new browser tab with the pdf view. Thanks!

```
return bytes(byte_file), 200, {
 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
 'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="nameofyourchoice.pdf"'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. It uses the PDF file returned directly from pdfkit and then uses a Flask Response for serving the file.

Here is the function that returns the PDF file:

```
def wish_lists_pdf(user=current_user):
    pdf_heading = "Thank you!"
    pdf_subheading = "Please find the Wish Lists you signed up to sponsor listed below."

    pdf_context = {
        'heading': pdf_heading,
        'subheading': pdf_subheading,
        'user': user,
    }
    css = os.path.join(basedir, 'static/main.css')
    pdf_content = render_template(
        'partials/email_lists_pdf.html', **pdf_context)

    path_wkhtmltopdf = app.config['WKHTMLTOPDF_EXE']
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)

    pdf_file = pdfkit.from_string(
        pdf_content, False, configuration=config, css=css)

    return pdf_file
```

And here is the view:

```
@bp.route('download_lists_pdf/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def download_lists_pdf(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
    pdf_file = wish_lists_pdf(user=user)

    response = Response(pdf_file)
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "inline; 'Wish List reminder page'"
    response.mimetype = 'application/pdf'
    return response
```

I think it would be more ideal if it would open in a new tab, or if it downloaded without opening in the browser, but this is good enough for now.